# Converting a nested for-each to use LINQ and JOIN

Tags: c#, linq

I have some `for-each` loops I am trying to convert to use `LINQ` with probably a `JOIN`
I started writing it myself but couldn't quite figure it out. I have posted my half attempt too.

and I started writing it like this but couldn't quite figure our how to proceed:

Comment: Could `if (!dic.ContainsKey(name)) continue` become `.Where(d => d.ContainsKey(item.PropName))`? It looks to me like that was missed out.

Comment: Also, if you find yourself using `object`, something may have gone wrong with keeping everything strongly typed.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes you can do .Where(d => d.ContainsKey(item.PropName)) yoo.  But no sorry "object" one has to stay, long story and too much code behin dit to explain but at the end yes it has to be object.

Comment: It is doable but I don't think it will be readable. And won't provide any other advantage over the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SelectMany you can achieve what you want with a little bit of weirdness like the below :

```
var result = metaData.SelectMany(r=> myDictionary,(meta,dict)=>  dict.TryGetValue(meta.PropName,out var val) ? new { val,meta } : null)
.Where(r=> r != null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.val.ToString()))
.Where(r=> r.val.GetType().IsArray ? 
       ((IEnumerable)r.val).Cast<object?>()
      .Select(v=> SomePrivateMethodCall(v, r.meta.PropertyType.GetElementType()))
                         .Any(result => !result) :
 !SomePrivateMethodCall(r.val, r.meta.PropertyType) )
.Select(r=> r.meta.PropName)).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks, getting there. It can't resolve the "item" where yo have v => CanCovertValueToType(v, item.PropertyType.GetElementType()) ... what's the one ?

Comment: @LonelySemiColon it should be meta, fixed.

Comment: I think you were missing a ")" after `.ToString())` to close the first `.Where` clause so should be `.Where(r=> r != null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.ToString()))`    but somehow still cannot resolve symbol for that item that we changed to meta.  Maybe a scope issue ?

Comment: @LonelySemiColon Yeap, need to select it in the outer scope

Comment: hmm still can't resolve the meta.  I see you have it defined in first line. hmm... also same place that can't see meta it also can't understand the type of `select` .... in this line: `.Select(v => SomePrivateMethodCall(v, meta.PropertyType.GetElementType()))` . It says the type arguments cannot be inferred.

Comment: @LonelySemiColon It had so many typos, but now should be okayish.

Comment: I appreciate you spending time.  I see how you fixed the meta issue, **nice!**  It did have a extra closing ")" before `.ToArray()` but hopefully last issue   is still that select it says "'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Select'"  in that line of code that has `? ((IEnumerable)r.val).Select(v`

Comment: @LonelySemiColon A cast might be needed there